# rspec assert disabled input value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2, capybara

I am using rspec2 for acceptance testing.

I have a textbox which is disabled and has a text.

Now what is a proper asserting statement to check that the particular disabled textbox has a particular value

Eg: my disabled textbox has a value "heaven"

`has_content?("heaven")` cant find a text heaven in page

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Has content is a capybara call if I'm not mistaken, not RSpec. (Watir-webdriver example)

```
@browser.text_field(:name => 'my_input').text.should include 'heaven'
```